# #1064 SQL Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand this is a common and annoying problem so before I ask for an explanation I just want to say sorry.

As the title says I've been getting a 1064 syntax error from my MySQL db I imported in to php myadmin running wamp and building through netbeans.

I've checked out how other posts on the matter and have done reading about proper syntax but cannot see what my problem is.

An explanation would be greatly appreciated as I really want to learn this and improve my skills.

(if you have any questions about my code please ask)

Here's my full code:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `mydb`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `follow`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `follow`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
`follow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`follow_current_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`follow_profile_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`follow_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `follow`
--

INSERT INTO `follow` (`follow_id`, `follow_current_user`,     `follow_profile_user`, `follow_timestamp`) VALUES
(13, 'dude', 'the', '2015-10-10 03:09:58'),


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_firstname` text NOT NULL,
`user_lastname` text NOT NULL,
`user_avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_shortbio` text,
`user_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_longbio` text,
`user_facebook` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_twitter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_linkedin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_stumbleupon` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_pinterest` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_googleplus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
`user_profession` text,
`user_gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_maritialstatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_address` text,
`user_backgroundpicture` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_joindate` date NOT NULL,
`user_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_skype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_github` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_youtube` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_vimeo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `user_email`, `user_password`,         `user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_avatar`, `user_shortbio`,     `user_username`, `user_longbio`, `user_facebook`, `user_twitter`,     `user_linkedin`, `user_stumbleupon`, `user_pinterest`, `user_googleplus`,     `user_website`, `user_dob`, `user_profession`, `user_gender`,     `user_maritialstatus`, `user_address`, `user_backgroundpicture`,  `user_joindate`, `user_country`, `user_skype`, `user_github`, `user_youtube`,  `user_vimeo`) VALUES
(1, 'me@gmail.com', '123password123', 'Forname', 'Surname',     '1470024_601216136604826_1065650331_n-884862517.jpg', 'Lorem ipsum.',     'username', 'Lorem ipsum', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'mysite.com',     '1987-11-11', 'Student', 'Male', NULL, 'kablah', 'untitled-90969185.jpg', '2015-    11-11', 'Country', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `view`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `view`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `view` (
`view_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`view_profile_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_current_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=123 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `view`
--

INSERT INTO `view` (`view_id`, `view_profile_user`, `view_current_user`,   `view_timestamp`) VALUES
(65, 'blub', 'rugsworth', '2015-10-18 19:30:56'),


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `follow`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`follow_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_username` (`user_username`);

--
-- Indexes for table `view`
--
ALTER TABLE `view`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`view_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `follow`
MODIFY `follow_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=18; 
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `view`
--
ALTER TABLE `view`
MODIFY `view_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=123;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And just the part of my code I think is causing the problem:

```
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `user_email`, `user_password`,         `user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_avatar`, `user_shortbio`,     `user_username`, `user_longbio`, `user_facebook`, `user_twitter`,     `user_linkedin`, `user_stumbleupon`, `user_pinterest`, `user_googleplus`,     `user_website`, `user_dob`, `user_profession`, `user_gender`,     `user_maritialstatus`, `user_address`, `user_backgroundpicture`,  `user_joindate`, `user_country`, `user_skype`, `user_github`, `user_youtube`,  `user_vimeo`) VALUES
(1, 'me@gmail.com', '123password123', 'Forname', 'Surname',     '1470024_601216136604826_1065650331_n-884862517.jpg', 'Lorem ipsum.',     'username', 'Lorem ipsum', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'mysite.com',     '1987-11-11', 'Student', 'Male', NULL, 'kablah', 'untitled-90969185.jpg', '2015-    11-11', 'Country', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `view`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `view`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `view` (
`view_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`view_profile_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_current_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`view_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=123 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `view`
--

INSERT INTO `view` (`view_id`, `view_profile_user`, `view_current_user`,   `view_timestamp`) VALUES
(65, 'blub', 'rugsworth', '2015-10-18 19:30:56'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of your `INSERT INTO 'view'` statement instead of a semicolon.

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO `view` (`view_id`, `view_profile_user`, `view_current_user`,   `view_timestamp`) 
VALUES (65, 'blub', 'rugsworth', '2015-10-18 19:30:56');
```

Does that fix it up?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Thanks though. I'm getting this error when uploading the sql file to phpadmin showing the piece of code I posted as where I think the error is.

Comment: Your other inserts also end in commas. Each SQL statement in a multi-statement file must end with semicolon.

Comment: @Garrus Well there may be other syntax errors but the commas at the end of the INSERT statements are certainly some of the syntax errors. Fix all of them and see if it improves. As Parfait said it happens at the end of every INSERT statement.

Comment: @Parfait that fixed most of the problems thanks very much :)